# javascript accordion - tracking time question

Tags: javascript, animation, time, accordion, settimeout

I was reading up on this javascript tutorial:
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutor...ccordion-menus
Basically, it shows you how to create an accordion using pure javascript, not jquery. All made sense to me until the actual part of tracking the animation. He says "Because of all that, the first thing we do in the animation function is figure out how much time has passed since the last animation iteration."
And then uses this code:
Code:

```
var elapsedTicks = curTick - lastTick;
```

lastTick is equal to the value of when the function was called (Date().getTime()) and curTick is equal to the value when the function was received. I don't understand why we are subtracting one from the other right here. I can't imagine that there's any noticeable time difference between these two values. Or maybe I'm missing something. Is that animate() function only called once every time a menu title is clicked or is it called several times to create the incremental animation effect?

```
setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + "," + TimeToSlide + ",'" + openAccordion + "','" + nID + "')", 33);
```

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> lastTick is equal to the value of when the function was called

`lastTick` is equal to the value when the function was **previously** called, on the last frame of animation. Since then, the script has given control back to the browser, asking to be called back in 33 milliseconds.

So `curTick-lastTick` will generally be *about* 33, but it could be much higher if the browser is lagged due to other stuff happening at the same time. This is why time-reading has to be done at all.

More usually in this sort of code, you'd store the time the animation *started* in a variable, and use `setInterval` to check it every so often, instead of setting a complete new timeout function each time (especially setting a timeout from a string, which is super-ugly).

eta:

> then runs the animate() function, which passes the current time

Nope. Look at the set-timeout call again:

```
setTimeout("animate(" + new Date().getTime() + ","...
```

That's making a string. `new Date().getTime()` is evaluated at timeout-setting time, *not* at timeout-calling time. It ends up making a string like:

```
setTimeout("animate(1275139344177, 250, 'Accordion4Content', 'Accordion4Content')", 33)
```

Which is the time at the end of the last frame, not the time the next frame's timeout will fire.

Putting JavaScript code in a string like this is super-confusing, rife with escaping problems, and generally regarded as really poor practice. It would be clearer to do it with an inline function:

```
var passTick= new Date().getTime();
setTimeout(function() {
    animate(passTick, TimeToSlide, openAccordion, nID);
}, 33);
```

Comment: Yeah it's that "previous" part that I don't understand. User clicks a title, runAccordion method is called, a few variables are set, and then the setTimeout function waits 33 milliseconds and then runs the animate() function, which passes the current time (Date.getTime()) as a parameter we call lastTick. So my brain is thinking that after  a user clicks the title, it waits 33 milliseconds and then triggers the animation. That's why I don't understand that lastTick could be equal to the value of function previously called.

Comment: Are you saying new Date().getTime() gets calculated first and THEN a period of 33 milliseconds occurs before animate() is called? If that's the case, then the tutorial makes sense to me.

Comment: Yes, `getTime()` is called and the Number result converted into a String. It then makes some code in a String, including that Number. The code made from that String executes when the timeout fires, 33ms after the String was created. Creating code out of Strings is bad, mmkay?